# Change sorting of the search listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We have a ruby on rails frontend(FE) and backend(BE). Data from the BE is inserted in the ES index after creating or updating.  User can search on FE in the index to find the right accommodation(apartments, villas, b&B).  We want to change 'manually' the sorting.  Example: accommodation X is selling slow, so we want this accommodation on top of the sorting.

What is the best approach ? thanks
remco

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be a using a [boosting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) with your existing query: where you can change the score of the documents adding a positive weight to slowing selling items.